# Android deep linking without corresponding URL

Tags: android, deep-linking

So from my understanding android application deep linking works like this:
You have a website with several pages. For each page, you define a deep link. This makes the app show up in google search instead of the website if the search term matches.

For example, if I add a deep link to http://example.com/entry/entryname and someone googles for "example entryname", he sees the deep link to the application instead of the website.

My question is, is it also possible to add your app in a "deep link like style" to googles search without having webpages for it? In this case, I have an app showing several wikipedia like entries to a specific topic. I also own the domain corresponding to the app. I now want my app to appear in google search if the user searchs for that topic and my app has an entry for the given search term.

Ie: user searches "example entryname" -> google search shows the deeplink of my app, although there is no http://example.com/entry/entryname

thanks in advance,
danijoo

Comment: In that case, it would be better to just have your own non-HTTP protocol (e.g., example://entry/entryname). See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app).

Comment: But with no http protocol, it wont show up in search, would it?

Comment: I think it still would as long as you follow the docs and Google indexes your app. I'm guessing it will only show in search for users who have your app installed?

Comment: I don't have a corresponding URL/Domain for my app, I only have my Android and iOS Native apps. So how to create a Deeplink ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here

[Support HTTP URLs in Your App](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app)

here clearly written that

"Note: If you have an app without corresponding web-page content, and you'd like it discovered by Google Search, fill out our app-only interest form. This is currently being tested with a few developers."